# to + inf vs to + '-ing'

Tags: gerunds, exam-questions, infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive

I have been doing an online test to check my English skills and found this:

> I was looking forward ____ at the new restaurant, but it was closed.
>
> **Incorrect** (your answer):
>   to eat
>
> **Correct**:
>   to eating

I had understood that after 'to' comes the infinitive form. Could anyone please explain why I am wrong in this case?

Comment: Please don't post images of text without transcribing the text in them. The text in images isn't searchable, and it's not accessible to people using screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

“Looking forward to eating” is correct here.

“Looking forward to” is acting like a phrasal verb that wants a direct object — **a noun**.

> I am looking forward to *the test*
>
> She is looking forward to *the new “Star Wars” movie*.
>
> They are looking forward to *a better future.*
>
> We are looking forward to running a marathon.
>
> I was looking forward to *eating at the restaurant.*

You’re right that “to” usually takes an infinitive verb.

> I want to *run a marathon*.

Some verbs can take either a noun, a gerund, **or** an infinitive verb as their “object”.

> I hate to run.
>
> I hate the test.
>
> I hate running.

Many very simple (usually 4-letter) verbs work this way:

- I want to swim,
- I love to swim,
- I like to swim,
- I plan to swim,
- I need to swim,
- I intend to swim

while other verbs do not:

- *No:* I enjoy to swim.

Unfortunately, “look forward to” is a verb that **doesn’t work this way**. It requires only a noun or a gerund.

> **Yes:** I look forward to running (the race).
>
> **Yes:** I look forward to the race.
>
> *No:* I look forward to run the race.

Answer (score 0):

"Looking forward to(something)" is a phrasal verb, meaning that you treat the phrase as you would a verb. Therefore, the something in question can only be either a 
1.+ing verb 
or
2.a noun

So, to eat+ing is the correct answer.

Comment: Some verbs can be followed by other verbs, such as “I like to write.”